# POSTGRESQL - Can Float8 datatype accommodate decimal(21,7)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table structure with float8 datatype.
I'm going to insert data from another system which has different decimal datatypes (Decimal (21,7) , decimal(16,7)) etc..
Will this cause any issue while inserting ?
I want to know what is the maximum value can float8 accommodate.

Comment: [The docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE) state "*double precision 8 bytes variable-precision, inexact 15 decimal digits precision*", so no this will not be enough to store up to 28 decimal digits precisely. Or do you only care about maximum values, and ignore loss of precision?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will lose precision:

```
SET extra_float_digits = 3;

SELECT 98765432109876.5432109::float8;
       float8        
---------------------
 98765432109876.5469
(1 row)
```

I set `extra_float_digits` so that PostgreSQL shows *all* decimal digits it can, even those that will contain rounding errors.